What does "tap a cross-Channel credit-network" mean?
I am reading a book named The Ascent of Money by Nial Ferguson. I came across the next line,

It was an immense operation, which depended on the brothers’ ability to tap their cross-Channel credit network and to manage large-scale bullion transfers.

I am not sure if what they mean by tapping in this exact context is the next definition by Merriam-Webster's dictionary

2: to let out or cause to flow by piercing or by drawing a plug from the containing vessel <~ a liquor>
3 a: to pierce so as to let out or draw off a fluid: draw off or drain off fluid or gas from <~ a cask> <~ the abdomen> <~ a rubber tree> <~ a blast furnace>
b: to open up (anything) so as to extract something: draw from <several railways ~ the region —C. L. White & G. T. Renner> <~ new sources of energy>"

Merriam-Webster. Webster's Third New International Dictionary Unabridged (Posición en Kindle1008652-1008657). Merriam-Webster. Edición de Kindle.
I guess he is using one of these meanings but I am unsure which one he uses.

As the discussion is about finance, it is quite likely that the phrase refers to the ability to interact with banks in both England and France (two nations that are across the English Channel from each other). The meaning of tap in this case is closest to definition 3b.

Why would it have anything to do with piercing or drawing fluid from a vessel?

It is a figure of speech based on tapping a barrel to get at its contents.     You draw from a resource you have in store.  The analogy:   to tap : barrel ::   call upon banks  :  a business loan     To tap : barrel :: to pull up from the minor league team :   a star player  Etc etc

@TimR  I guess these guys were somehow depleting their gold stock to pay for that war. In other words, this figure of speech implies that they were using their own financial resources to finance the Duke of Wellington's war. Am I right?

@Quique The figure of speech means merely to draw on some available resource and  doesn't get into issues of possession or ownership. The phrase "depended on the brothers' abillity to tap their cross-channel credit network" implies borrowing to me,  because of "credit network". They relied on their perceived creditworthiness. I don't know enough about international finance to opine on whether the "bullion transfers" involved moving bullion they owned as collateral  -- "their own financial resources" --  or if they were borrowing bullion and writing IOUs. Was it the former or the latter?

@TimR I am sorry, but the book does not provide further details. The Ascent of Money by Nial Ferguson is the title.

He's great isn't he? Everyone should read that book. tap there just means to use that credit network.  It is also sometimes: tap into something.

Tap in this context means “leverage” or “make use of.” The corresponding dictionary entry would be
to draw out, from, or upon

draw out? Not really...

"tap" = "tap into".  If you use your home equity to borrow money you are "tapping" or "tapping into" your home equity.  These guys are using their cross channel financial network to move Gold.

OP has asked about the meaning of a term in an extract from The Ascent of Money by Niall Ferguson.

What does "tap a cross-Channel credit-network mean?
It was an immense operation, which depended on the brothers’ ability to tap their cross-Channel credit network and to manage large-scale bullion transfers.

I. Sentence Meaning:
This sentence refers to the Rothschild brothers' pivotal role in financing the British war effort during the Napoleonic Wars and managing financial operations between London and Paris (and beyond).
The Rothschilds leveraged their expertise in moving gold and silver (bullion) to facilitate these transactions.
Their network ensured that funds could be converted into bullion in London and safely transported or transferred to Paris and other European locations, ultimately supporting Britain and its allies.
II. Meaning of the Terms:

The brothers: The five Rothschild brothers, who established banking branches in Frankfurt, London, Paris, Vienna, and Naples.

Tap: From Collins Dictionary: tap, sense 4 If you tap a resource or situation, you make use of it by getting from it something that you need or want.
Example: The company is tapping shareholders for £15.8 million. [VERB noun + for].
This meaning aligns with the Rothschilds "making use of" their credit network to access financial resources.

Cross-Channel: Refers to operations across the English Channel, particularly between London and Paris. However, the Rothschilds' operations extended across Europe, with branches in Frankfurt, Vienna, and Naples, to support Britain's allies.


III. Relevant extracts from Wikipedia:.
The Rothschild family

The family rose to prominence with Mayer Amschel Rothschild   managed to bequeath his wealth and established an international banking family through his five sons, who established businesses in Paris, Frankfurt, London, Vienna, and Naples.
From London in 1813 to 1815, Nathan Mayer Rothschild was instrumental in almost single-handedly financing the British war effort, organising the shipment of bullion to the Duke of Wellington's armies across Europe, as well as arranging the payment of British financial subsidies to their continental allies.
In 1815 alone, the Rothschilds provided £9.8 million (equivalent to about £850 million in 2023) in subsidy loans to Britain's continental allies.
The brothers helped coordinate Rothschild activities across the continent, and the family developed a network of agents, shippers and couriers to transport gold across war-torn Europe.


tapping shareholders for x means getting money from them. Here, tapping just means using.

@Lambie I have checked different dictionary meanings.If you tap a resource or you make use of it by getting from it thing you need or want.
This defi is similar to the context of the Rothschild brothers accessing and utilizing their cross-Channel credit network to facilitate large-scale financial operations. It captures the idea of using their financial network for a specific purpose, such as supporting the British war effort.
Example : "The company is tapping shareholders for £15.8 million." is similar the Rothschilds "tapping" their credit network to meet financial demands.

To tap shareholders for some amount means to raise that amount from them. BUT tap a credit network is just use it. He doesn't say how. Your answer is very confusing and this is very simple.

@Lambie So you think using a credit network in this context is similar to "using an umbrella" in the rain.

@Lambie If its so simple, why is OP asking the question. The sentence mentions "immense operation". It is not "Thie verb is often used in business/financial contexts" as your answer mentions. But it is talking about wartime Europe.

Oxford Dictionaries via google
2.
exploit or draw a supply from (a resource).
"clients from industry seeking to tap Philadelphia's resources of expertise"
Similar:
draw on
exploit
milk
make use of
put to use
use
utilize
the brothers’ ability to tap [use or make use of] their cross-Channel credit network
This verb is often used in business/financial contexts.

Do your homework properly? What does "tap a cross-Channel credit-network mean?
It's your bad habit of down voting my answer and then giving another answer. How does your answer explain the question asked in the title?
